# wordpress 3.8.1 update message

Tags: wordpress

I just updated my WordPress sites to 3.8.1 but the Dashboard is showing a message saying that I need to update even though I performed the update successfully.Is it a bug or what went wrong?

How can we make this problem disappear?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the update completed successfully, then it is a bug. Do report it to WP.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to logout and login again and check if it is still reporting the same message. If it does do one more time the update

Comment: Thank you.I'll do it and let you know.